# Play MP3 and Sync With Image Changes

Tags: vb.net, uwp, mp3

I am looking to play an embedded MP3 file, and at specific durations within the playback to cause an image to change. This would be a UWP project in Visual Basic. Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: There are hundreds of ways to play an Mp3 file. Give us some hints to where to start, don't you think ? How does your classes looks like ? Does your application features timing control (play, pause, slider...) ? Solutions varies from ultra simple to utterly complex depending on what you've done.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Karl. I've found much of what I needed. The MediaElement plays an MP3 file, at least from a URL, and there's the Me.MediaElement1.Position.ToString value which I can parse and use within a timer control to manipulate the image at planned intervals.

Comment: If your solution is worked, you should be able to make it as answer.